# Partition In Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows

[image]
I installed Ubuntu only in my drive. I didn't make any partition. I erased partition and installed Ubuntu. I want make partition to install Windows alongside. But I can't edit partition.

Comment: You cannot edit a partition that is in use; boot from a LiveUSB instead. Best practice is usually to install Windows first, since the Windows installer will usually try to reformat the entire disk.

Answer (score 0):

First. if you used MBR partition table you cannot install windows alongside you have write partition table again which will erase all data on disk.
so first make sure you have GPT partition table using gparted then proceed

You have to use Ubuntu live flash drive/cd to resize partitions.

Here are steps
1. Make bootable flash drive

`sudo umount /dev/sdx #x is character designated to your usb`

`sudo dd bs=4M if=input.iso of=/dev/sdx conv=fdatasync`

You can also use other tools to make bootable USB Google them.
OR
Make gparted live flash drive and use it to resize partitions

2. Boot from live usb and select try Ubuntu (do not install)
3. Open gparted and resize the partitions
4. If gparted won't work then use kde partition manager

`sudo apt install partitionmanager`

Make sure you do everything after step 1 using live Ubuntu flash drive.

If you have problems booting boot using nomodeset.

Comment: Both Ubuntu and Windows install in the boot mode, that you boot installer in. If you want UEFI/gpt you must boot install media in UEFI mode. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt. And Windows only boots in BIOS boot mode from MBR, but must have a primary NTFS partition with boot flag. If your boot mode changes partitioning you then erase drive. Just be sure to have good backups, regardless of which way you install.

Answer (score 0):

Windows needs several smaller partitions for the operating system to work and it is easiest done by letting the windows installer make those other partitions needed on the disk. you should first erase the disk install windows then install Ubuntu if you want them to coincide on the same disk. 
so for example

```
first back up files wanted from Ubuntu 

second boot into windows install disk choose custom installation

third delete Ubuntu and swap partition then click on new make the size small enough for both windows and Ubuntu to work correctly. 

fourth  you click on new the windows installer will ask you to create other partitions needed.  

fifth continue and complete installation of windows 

sixth boot into Ubuntu ISO via DVD or flash drive

seventh when the prompt comes up click either install along side windows or do something else and make your own partitions and mount points 

eighth continue and complete Ubuntu installation
```